# Animated Typography

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way of animating text in such a way that each individual character all start from the same point and end up forming a sentence? (like all the letters fly through the air effect)

I know this can be easily done in Flash or a GIF but I don't want to have to embed my text.

And I'm not talking about the Jquery animate () function which changes the CSS.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: do you mean you want to have a pure javascript (no jQuery, no other library) solution?

Comment: The simplest solution would be the best! So I really don't mind using vanilla or Jquery

Answer (score 2):

Put each character into an individual `<span>` tag. You can then select each individual tag and change its position independently from the others.

Comment: That sounds like a whole lot of work for a couple of paragraphs of text

Comment: You can use JavaScript to break the text content of an element into individual `span`s containing one character each as well.